# Laravel 4 : Sidebar is not clickable

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I have here in my views a sidebar and I got problem because the sidebar aren't clickable. I don't know what's the problem I read online about this problem but  I do the right thing, Please can anyone help to check this out?

Do check my code below:

I have a master.blade.php: The code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      @include('layouts.head')
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- START PAGE CONTAINER -->
        <div class="page-container">

            @include('layouts.sidebar')

            <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
            <div class="page-content">

                @include('layouts.navigation')
                @include('layouts.breadcrumb')
                <!-- PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->
                <div class="page-content-wrap">
                   @yield('content')
                </div>
                <!-- END PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE CONTAINER -->

        @include('layouts.messagebox')

        <!-- START PRELOADS -->
        <audio id="audio-alert" src="audio/alert.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
        <audio id="audio-fail" src="audio/fail.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
        <!-- END PRELOADS -->

    <!-- START SCRIPTS -->
        <!-- START PLUGINS -->
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js');}}

        <!-- END PLUGINS -->

        <!-- START THIS PAGE PLUGINS-->
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/icheck/icheck.min.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/mcustomscrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/scrolltotop/scrolltopcontrol.js');}}

        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/morris/raphael-min.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/rickshaw/d3.v3.js');}}
        <!-- {{HTML::script('js/plugins/rickshaw/rickshaw.min.js');}} -->
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/owl/owl.carousel.min.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.js');}}

        <!-- END THIS PAGE PLUGINS-->

        <!-- START TEMPLATE -->
        {{HTML::script('js/ixepms.js');}}
        <!-- {{HTML::script('js/settings.js');}} -->
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/actions.js');}}
        {{HTML::script('js/demo_dashboard.js');}}
        <!-- END TEMPLATE -->
        <!--START DATA TABLE TEMPLATES PLUGIN-->
        {{HTML::script('js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}
        <!--END DATA TABLE TEMPLATES PLUGIN-->
        @yield('script')
        @yield('department_script')

    <!-- END SCRIPTS -->
    </body>
</html>
```

As what you have noticed in the code, I @include in the masterpage a sidebar

layouts/sidebar.blade.php : Code below

```
<!-- START PAGE SIDEBAR -->
            <div class="page-sidebar">
                <!-- START X-NAVIGATION -->
                <ul class="x-navigation">
                    @include('layouts.profile')
                    <li class="xn-title">Navigation</li>
                      <li class="xn-openable">
                        <a href="javascript:;"><span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span> <span class="xn-text">Dashboards</span></a>
                        <ul>

                           <!-- <li><a href="{{{URL::to('task/dash',1)}}}"><span class="fa fa-desktop"></span> <span class="xn-text">General Dashboard</span></a></li> -->

                           <li><a href="{{{URL::to('task/dash',2)}}}"><span class="fa fa-desktop"></span> <span class="xn-text">General Dashboard</span></a></li>
                           <li><a href="{{{URL::to('task/dash',3)}}}"><span class="fa fa-desktop"></span> <span class="xn-text">My Dashboard</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="xn-openable">
                        <a href=""><span class="fa fa-users"></span> <span class="xn-text"> Manage Users</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                        <li><a href="{{{route('user.index')}}}"><span class="fa fa-file"></span> <span class="xn-text">Users</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-file-text"></span> <span class="xn-text">Add New User</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-file-text-o"></span> <span class="xn-text">View Profile</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-file-text-o"></span> <span class="xn-text">Deactivated Users</span></a></li>

                                </ul>
                        </li>
                         <li class="xn-openable">
                            <a href=""><span class="fa fa-files-o"></span> <span class="xn-text">Assessment</span></a>

                                <ul>
                                        <li><a href="{{ route('assessment.index') }}"><span class="fa fa-file"></span> <span class="xn-text">Do My Assessment</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ route('assessment.index') }}"><span class="fa fa-file-text"></span> <span class="xn-text">Peer Assessment</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ route('assessment.index') }}"><span class="fa fa-file-text-o"></span> <span class="xn-text">Supervisorial Assessment</span></a></li>

                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{{route('behavioralsub.index')}}}"><span class="fa fa-folder-open"></span> <span class="xn-text">Manage Assessments</span></a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- END X-NAVIGATION -->
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE SIDEBAR -->
```

Can you check why does my sidebar aren't clickable?

Comment: It might be better to include the outputted html from these templates.

Comment: Did you try using the element inspector? It's easier to see what is going wrong in there. See if you get any errors in there.

Answer (score 0):

Use element inspector... you might have some element (like a div, perhaps `.page-content`) over your side bar.